# Move a document to another collection with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to move a document to another collection in MongoDB based on this approach [Saving Mongoose object into two collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15115553/3137109).

In the example he shows how to create two new objects. My goal is to move it from one collection to another.

To be a bit more specific: In a document I have a list of tasks which eventually get completed and should then be moved inside this document to another array. However I need to be able to query all the unfinished and this should be possible with two collections.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So you have to register the Schema twice

```
let ChangeSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    version: Number
})

mongoose.model('First', ChangeSchema)
mongoose.model('Second', ChangeSchema)
```

Then you can swap 'em like this

```
mongoose.model('First').findOne({ _id: id }, function(err, result) {

    let swap = new (mongoose.model('Second'))(result.toJSON()) //or result.toObject
    /* you could set a new id
    swap._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
    swap.isNew = true
    */

    result.remove()
    swap.save()

    // swap is now in a better place

})
```

Comment: I'm not able to get this solution to work. I get an error `VersionError: No matching document found for id "58b1512b8f361b717254fa59"` Almost pointlessly I found that if I manually injected the documents into the collection first, then I'd get no such error, leading me to believe that I'm missing a step regarding the id part. Can anyone add more detail to this solution?

Comment: @stuffyjoelab you need to have a document to switch in the first place. `No matching document found for id "58b1512b8f361b717254fa59"` tells you that there is no document with his id.

Comment: A bit late but... Unless the property `_id` in the schema is set to a `String` type then mongoose will expect an `ObjectId`. If your id is a string and mongoose is expecting an object id use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)`, validate beforehand with `mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)` if necessary

Comment: as @Ben said mongoose is expecting an argument of type `objectId`. There is a method to find a document by `ID mongoose.model.findById(_id)` this will return the required document

Comment: @roskelld converting the object to plain object(JSON) solves the problem.

Comment: will this execute synchronously?

Answer (score 0):

The solution above is correct but will be too slow for a massive amount of documents if "awaited" for `remove` and `save`, or may flood an instance if it doesn't.

Here's a simple alteration for semi-bulk parallel action

```js
  // use "strict: false" so we won't have to declare schema in the script
  const First = mongoose.model('ActionsNewCollection', new mongoose.Schema({}, {collection: `first`, strict: false}))
  const Second = mongoose.model('ActionsNewCollection', new mongoose.Schema({}, {collection: `second`, strict: false}))


  const cursor = First.find({}).cursor();

  let moved_actions = []
  let moved_actions_ids = []
  for (let action = await cursor.next(); action != null; action = await cursor.next()) {

    let actions_json = action.toJSON()
    moved_actions.push(actions_json)
    moved_actions_ids.push(actions_json._id)

    // Every 100, stop and wait for them to be done
    if (moved_actions.length > 300) {
      let inserts = [Second.insertMany(moved_actions.slice(0,100)), Second.insertMany(moved_actions.slice(100,200)), Second.insertMany(moved_actions.slice(200))]
      let deletes = [First.deleteMany({_id: { $in: moved_actions_ids.slice(0,100)}}), First.deleteMany({_id: { $in: moved_actions_ids.slice(100,200)}}), First.deleteMany({_id: { $in: moved_actions_ids.slice(200)}})]
      await Promise.all(inserts)
      await Promise.all(deletes)
      moved_actions = []
      moved_actions_ids = []
    }
  }
```